# Multiple datasources in one LinqPad query to compare Dynamics 365 and Dynamics NAV data

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, linqpad

I am currently facing the need to access Dynamics 365 online and Dynamics NAV to compare data in both systems. Instead of using PowerBI, I would prefer more of a code-driven approach, so I tried LinqPad.

My idea was to fetch the data from both systems, run a comparison method and dump whatever needs to be dumped.

Unfortunately I am struggling with this approach, as it looks like I can not use multiple connections to unrelated systems in one query.

Any ideas, how to solve this? Perhaps export to csv and use that in another query?

Regards

Sven

Comment: Yes, you can not use different sources in one query, it is SQL limitation. So just materialize objects from different sources by ToList() and compare them.

Comment: I can not do that either, as LinqPad will not let me use multiple connections. no matter if I materialize the results, or not.

Comment: How do you connect to the data sources?